# Do not use class member function inside class

Tags: c++, oop

I want to write an object-oriented wrapper around old C-style functions, while keeping the actual function names the same. Take a look at an example:

```
#include <iostream>

void doStuff(int a, float b)
{
    std::cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << "\n";
}

class Stuff
{
    private:
        int a;
        float b;

    public:
        Stuff(int newA, float newB) : a(newA), b(newB) { }

        int getA() { return a; }
        float getB() { return b; }
};

class Widget
{
    public:
        void doStuff(Stuff s)
        {
            doStuff(s.getA(), s.getB());            //error: no matching function for call to 'Widget::doStuff(int, float)'
        }
};

int main()
{
    Widget w;

    w.doStuff(Stuff(42, 3.14f));

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, `void doStuff(int a, float b)` is the old C-function. Because in my real code, its equivalent is in an external library/header file, I cannot change its name. Next, `Stuff` is a container for keeping the values `void doStuff(int a, float b)` needs. The important things happen in `Widget`: `void Widget::doStuff(Stuff s)` should be the actual wrapper. I now expect `doStuff(s.getA(), s.getB())` to call the old C-style function `void doStuff(int a, int b)` but the compilation fails with the given error.

Is it possible to make this code work without changing the name of the both `doStuff` functions? One option I already thought of is surrounding `void doStuff(int a, float b)` by some namespace. This works, but seems like very bad practice to me.

My compiler is mingw-w64 with g++ 5.2.0, so C++11 and C++14 are available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `doStuff(Stuff s)` method in your class hides the global function `doStuff(int a, float b)`. If you want to call the global `doStuff` function, you have to use the scope resolution operator `::` (`::doStuff(s.getA(), s.getB());`)

Answer (score 0):

Try making your call like this:

```
::doStuff(s.getA(), s.getB());
```